# How to get/read the name of the windows user who is editing the word document?

Tags: office-js

I have recently started working on Microsoft word add ins , I would like to know if there is any way to get/read the name of the windows user who is 
editing the word document using Office.JS API.

Hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly at the moment. There is a new set of SSO functionality that just went into Preview however which would allow you to fetch the current user's profile from [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user).

See [Enable single sign-on for Office Add-ins (preview)](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins) for details on how this works.

Comment: Just to clarify. When using SSO, if all you need is an ID of the user, you can get that from the `preferred_username` property of the access token that your add-in receives from the Office host. You don't have to go to Microsoft Graph.