# office.js read worksheet properties

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

In office.js, is it possible to read worksheet properties?

Actually, someone develop a excel addin using VSTO, there they set a worksheet property. Now the excel web addin that I am developing, I need to read that property. Not sure if it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to read (and set) document properties using Office.js was recently made available as part of [API Requirement Set](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets) **ExcelApi 1.7**. This requirement set is currently in **Beta**, so to use this API feature:

- You'll need to reference the **beta** CDN: `https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js`
- If you're using TypeScript, you'll want to reference the **beta** d.ts file: `https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.d.ts`
- You must be using a sufficiently recent build of Excel (e.g., [Office Insiders Fast](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-insider)). If you're not on a sufficiently recent build and try to use the read document properties API, an `ApiNotFound` error will be thrown.

The following code snippet shows show to read document properties (using JavaScript):

```
Excel.run(function (context) {
    var docProperties = context.workbook.properties;

    // Load a combination of read-only 
    // and writeable document properties.
    docProperties.load("author, lastAuthor, revisionNumber, title, subject, keywords, comments, category, manager, company, creationDate");

    return context.sync()
        .then(function () {

            // Write the document properties to the console.
            console.log("Author: " + docProperties.author);
            console.log("Last author : " + docProperties.lastAuthor);
            console.log("Revision number: " + docProperties.revisionNumber);
            console.log("Title: " + docProperties.title);
            console.log("Subject: " + docProperties.subject);
            console.log("Keywords: " + docProperties.keywords);
            console.log("Comments: " + docProperties.comments);
            console.log("Category: " + docProperties.category);
            console.log("Manager: " + docProperties.manager);
            console.log("Company: " + docProperties.company);
            console.log("Workbook creation date: " + docProperties.creationDate.toDateString());
        });
}).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
```

And here's the same snippet, but in TypeScript:

```
Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let docProperties = context.workbook.properties;

    // Load a combination of read-only 
    // and writeable document properties.
    docProperties.load("author, lastAuthor, revisionNumber, title, subject, keywords, comments, category, manager, company, creationDate");

    await context.sync();

    // Write the document properties to the console.
    console.log("Author: " + docProperties.author);
    console.log("Last author : " + docProperties.lastAuthor);
    console.log("Revision number: " + docProperties.revisionNumber);
    console.log("Title: " + docProperties.title);
    console.log("Subject: " + docProperties.subject);
    console.log("Keywords: " + docProperties.keywords);
    console.log("Comments: " + docProperties.comments);
    console.log("Category: " + docProperties.category);
    console.log("Manager: " + docProperties.manager);
    console.log("Company: " + docProperties.company);
    console.log("Workbook creation date: " + docProperties.creationDate.toDateString());
});
```

Comment: thanks @Kim for your reply. It is working when I tried on excel online but not on the excel desktop. I think it is because I don't have "Office Insider Fast". I have Office 365 ProPlus subscription. I could not find the Office Insider tile in the Account page of excel desktop as mentioned in the Office Insider home page https://products.office.com/en-us/office-insider?tab=Windows-Desktop

Comment: and also here we are reading workbook properties. Do you know how to read worksheet properties ?

Comment: @amitavak -- format-related properties (for a cell or range of cells) like font, fill, borders, alignment, etc. can be accessed via the Range object (Range.format), while Worksheet-related properties like name, position, and visibility can be accessed via the Worksheet object. If you can provide more information about what you mean by "worksheet properties", I can try to provide more specific guidance.

Comment: so the property is set from another excel addin built with VSTO. There they use the below code example to set the property
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-customproperties-property-excel
I like to read this custom worksheet property from office.js

Comment: @amitavak -- thanks for the additional information. I suspect that getting/setting custom properties on a **worksheet** (instead of on a **workbook**, as my answer describes) is not yet supported by Office.js, but I have reached out to SMEs to confirm whether or not that is the case. I will add another comment here if I'm able to get confirmation one way or the other.

Comment: @KimBrandl Why `console.log("Title: " + docProperties.title);` log an empty string? i want to get my document title? thanks.

Comment: @MHS -- the **title** property that's being read (and logged to the console) in my example is the file-level attribute **title** that is displayed under **Properties** if you select **File >> Info** (in Excel running on Windows Desktop). It is not the "title" (text) that you see at that the top of your document, or the name of the file itself. I'd suspect that if you select **File >> Info**, you'll see that the **Title** field is not populated (under **Properties**) -- it won't be populated unless you've explicitly set it.

Comment: Many thanks @KimBrandl . Is there any way to get the "title" that seen at that the top of the document? also is that possible to get logged in user info (email, username ,...) ?

Comment: @MHS -- can you please post these questions as new (separate) questions here on Stack Overflow (each with the office-js tag)? That way, you're more likely to get a good response, and others are more likely to benefit from the answers in the future as well. Thanks!

Comment: @KimBrandl thanks, sure, this is the question that i posted before: [document-title-in-office-365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288851/how-can-i-get-the-document-title-in-office-365-javascript-api)

Comment: @MHS -- thanks for the link, I'll take a look at that post. Also, re your question about getting logged-in user info -- see this Answer for more info on that:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44024992/how-to-get-read-the-name-of-the-windows-user-who-is-editing-the-word-document.

Comment: is it now possible to get custom properties on a **worksheet** (instead of on a workbook)?